# Display elements only if they are filled with text, Empty rule not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have built a little filter application with a widget. Now I have some filter tags which show you what kind of filter options you have chosen. Now If there is no filter selected the tags must be hidden. I figured out how to do that with a javascript function. The css empty rule does not work with the widget. 
But I cannot figure out how to make them visible again.

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('display');

for (let x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
    let div = divs[x];
    let content =  div.innerText.trim();
    console.log("Trim Test" + content);

    if (content == '') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else{
        div.style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="tags123">
<span id="display" class="display"> <p id="display1" class="display1"></p></span>
<span id="display" class="display"> <p id="display3" class="display3"></p></span>
<span id="display" class="display"> <p id="display2" class="display2"></p></span>
  </div>
```

The if condition works, my tags are hidden. But the else condition does not seem to trigger If I enter something in the Tags.
I have attached two pictures to show the if condition is working. Do I have to enclose it with some event listener ? Thank you for your time.  [image]

[image]

Comment: I dont get your question. I just edited your snippet to have some text in one of the relevant spans and it did show up. Can you provide more context? What was the css you tried?

Comment: Well without the function you see above, you get the empty tags which you can see in the photo. 
My function makes them invisible but If I choose some filter it should display them again. 
This is done via a widget its not static.
The widget does not support css empty rule like I said.

Comment: You you put something in the tags? How are you putting it in the tags? That code only runs when it is evaluated, it does not keep automatically running. So whatever is setting the text needs to call something to make the elements appear.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me how your widget interacts with your markup, but a simple way to toggle the visibility of empty elements would be to filter out the ones with content and use a class that gets toggled on click, like so:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const items = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

btn.onclick = () => [...items]
  .filter(i => !i.textContent)
  .forEach(i => i.classList.toggle('hidden'));
```

```css
.foo::after {
  content: 'x';
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.foo.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">toggle visibilty</button>
<div>
  <span class="foo">Text</span>
  <span class="foo"></span>
  <span class="foo"></span>
</div>
```